# Importación en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Ayer creé una base de datos en Mysql. Hoy he decidido exportar el script y volver a importar ese mismo script. Para mi sorpresa no consigo hacerlo.
Estas son las sentencias SQL de una de las tablas( ya que falla en todas pongo una solo)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ap_trans;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE ap_trans (
  index int NOT NULL,
  id_origen int NOT NULL,
  id_destino int NOT NULL,
  read char(1) NOT NULL,
  stack char(1) NOT NULL,
  push varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('index'),
  KEY idstate-1_idx ('id_origen'),
  KEY idstate-2_idx ('id_destino'),
  CONSTRAINT idstate-1 FOREIGN KEY ('id_origen') REFERENCES estados ('id_state'),
  CONSTRAINT idstate-2 FOREIGN KEY ('id_destino') REFERENCES estados ('id_state')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Me da este error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 27: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int NOT NULL,
  id_origen int NOT NULL,
  id_destino int NOT NULL,
  read char(1' at line 2
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

La línea 27 es la de **index int NOT NULL**. Me da el mismo error en todas las tablas.
¿Cual puede ser el fallo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Las estás importando en otra base de datos dentro del mismo servidor? La estás importando en otro servidor? Las estás importando en un motor de bases de datos con la misma versión? Es un motor de bases de datos diferente?

Comment: INDEX es una [palabra reservada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que index es palabra reservada, ver acá la lista [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Debes cambiar el nombre o colocar entre comillas invertidas

```
`index` int NOT NULL
```

Comment: Es verdad!! Pero después falla en KEY idstate_1_idx ('id_origen'),
  KEY idstate_2_idx ('id_destino'), Me dice que "(" is not valid at this position for this server version. Sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Y si borras esas líneas??

Comment: A decir verdad, Mpy, supongo que lo que falla es **KEY idstate-1_idx ('id_origen']...** porque ese guión antes del 1 es alto, y no bajo. Revisa eso, y mejor pon todos bajos, si acaso